# Decrease space before and after chapter in fncychap

Tags: spacing, sectioning, chapters, fncychap

I would like to decrease the space before and after the chapter name due to space constraints. I am using the `fncychap`. Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Amazing}
    \lipsum[1-5] % filler text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Are you sure you want to use the `Glenn` style? In my opinion, long titles look specially ugly (not that short ones are pretty).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina What do you recommend? I am writing a report and I don't want to use the ugly default one.

Comment: If you want a framed title, I would suggest you to use the titlesec package. Let me provide an answer with both options.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Okay great. I would like to have a professional looking report as much as possible.

Comment: I have provided an example of a framed title using `titlesec`. However, if you are looking for a professional report, I would suggest you not to use frames at all. The documentation for the `memoir` document class has several chapter styles that might give you some good ideas for your titles.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina So you recommend that I use the `memoir` class for the report and use its chapter style and layout to make my report?

Comment: That would be a possibility, but I don't know if you like `memoir` or have ever used it; another option is to continue using `report`, select a style that you like from the `memoir` documentation, and then design it with `titlesec` to be used with `report`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The quickest way is to patch the appropriate commands. To change the spacing before the titles, you need to patch `\@makechapterhead` (for numbered chapters) and `\@makeschapterhead` (for unnumbered chapters); to change the spacing after the tiles, you need to patch `\DOTI` (for numbered chapters) and `\DOTIS` (for unnumbered chapters). A little example (the second argument for `\patchcmd` contains the default values; the third argument, the modified values):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[Glenn]{fncychap}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{-20\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@makeschapterhead}{\vspace*{50\p@}}{\vspace*{-20\p@}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTI}{\vskip 80\p@}{\vskip 40\p@}{}{}
\patchcmd{\DOTIS}{\vskip 40\p@}{\vskip 0\p@}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Amazing}
    \lipsum[1-5] % filler text
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I would suggest you *not* to use this style; long titles won't look good, You could consider using a framed title built with the help of the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package; here's a simple example (the vertical spacing before and after the title is set using the second and third arguments for `\titlespacing*`):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text

\makeatletter
\titleformat{\chapter}[frame]
  {\normalfont}{\filright\enspace \@chapapp~\thechapter\enspace}
  {8pt}{\LARGE\bfseries\filcenter}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}
  {0pt}{0pt}{20pt}

\makeatother

\begin{document}
    \chapter{Amazing}
    \lipsum[1-5] % filler text
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for the advice not to use `fncychap` :)

Comment: Is it possible to decrease the size from the top? The report I am writing has specific page constraints and the space that is left at the top can be used for information :)

Comment: @gekkostate Sure; you can use a negative value for the length in the second argument for `\titlespacing*`.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina can you please break down your second example for us novices in title formatting?