# Make \leftmark raggedright

Tags: header-footer, scrlayer-scrpage

As described in [this article](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248340/remove-empty-space-before-chapter-contents), I’m trying to replicate a CD. Following the solution given over there, I use `scrlayer` to format the chapter titles which are displayed via `\leftmark`. Now, the CD-manual states that chapter titles should be left aligned without hyphenation. But putting `\raggedright` in the layer definition doesn’t show any effect. Is there a way to achieve this?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[%
   openany
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[%
  a4paper
  ,inner=26mm
  ,outer=7mm
  ,top=81.5mm
  ,bottom=31.5mm
  ,headheight=32pt
  ,headsep=54mm
  ,showframe
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  oddpage,
  area={26mm}{\dimexpr14mm\relax}{\textwidth}{32pt},
  contents={\vfill\hfill\pagemark}
]{hc.head.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=hc.head.odd,
  evenpage,
  hoffset=7mm,
  contents={\vfill\pagemark}
]{hc.head.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground
  ,headsep
  ,addvoffset=-3mm
  ,contents={\vfill\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\layerwidth}{3pt}}
]{hc.headsep.bottom.line}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  ,footskip,
  ,contents={\vfill\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\layerwidth}{.5pt}}
]{hc.footskip.bottom.line}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=hc.headsep.bottom.line,
  ,addvoffset=-1mm
  ,contents={\vfill{\strut\usekomafont{chapter}\raggedright\leftmark\nobreak\strut}}
]{hc.headsep}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{plain.hc}{%
  hc.head.odd,hc.head.even,%
  hc.headsep.bottom.line,%
  hc.footskip.bottom.line%
}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{chapterpage.hc}{%
  hc.head.odd,hc.head.even,%
  hc.headsep,%
  hc.headsep.bottom.line,%
  hc.footskip.bottom.line%
}
\DeclarePageStyleAlias{plain}{plain.hc}
\DeclarePageStyleAlias{chapterpage}{chapterpage.hc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{32pt}{30.5pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\fontsize{32pt}{30.5pt}\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\headchapter{\@ifstar{\@sheadchapter}{\@headchapter}}
\newcommand*\@headchapter[1]{%
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{chapterpage}\refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \markleft{\thechapter\enskip#1}%
  \addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{#1}%
}
\newcommand*\@sheadchapter[1]{%
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{chapterpage}%
  \markleft{#1}%
}
\newcommand\addheadchap[1]{%
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{chapterpage}%
  \markleft{#1}%
  \addchaptertocentry{}{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\deftocheading{toc}{\headchapter*{\contentsname}}

\begin{document}
\addheadchap{Test texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use `\raggedchapter` - it is predefined as `\raggedright` use a `\parbox`

```
contents={\vfill\parbox{\layerwidth}{\raggedchapter\usekomafont{chapter}\leftmark\strut}}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass[%
   openany
  ]{scrbook}
\usepackage[%
  a4paper
  ,inner=26mm
  ,outer=7mm
  ,top=81.5mm
  ,bottom=31.5mm
  ,headheight=32pt
  ,headsep=54mm
  ,showframe
  ]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  oddpage,
  area={26mm}{\dimexpr14mm\relax}{\textwidth}{32pt},
  contents={\vfill\hfill\pagemark}
]{hc.head.odd}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=hc.head.odd,
  evenpage,
  hoffset=7mm,
  contents={\vfill\pagemark}
]{hc.head.even}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground
  ,headsep
  ,addvoffset=-3mm
  ,contents={\vfill\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\layerwidth}{3pt}}
]{hc.headsep.bottom.line}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  foreground,
  ,footskip,
  ,contents={\vfill\rule[-\dp\strutbox]{\layerwidth}{.5pt}}
]{hc.footskip.bottom.line}
\DeclareNewLayer[
  clone=hc.headsep.bottom.line,
  ,addvoffset=-1mm,
  ,contents={\vfill\parbox{\layerwidth}{%
    \raggedchapter\usekomafont{chapter}\leftmark\strut}}
]{hc.headsep}

\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{plain.hc}{%
  hc.head.odd,hc.head.even,%
  hc.headsep.bottom.line,%
  hc.footskip.bottom.line%
}
\DeclareNewPageStyleByLayers{chapterpage.hc}{%
  hc.head.odd,hc.head.even,%
  hc.headsep,%
  hc.headsep.bottom.line,%
  hc.footskip.bottom.line%
}
\DeclarePageStyleAlias{plain}{plain.hc}
\DeclarePageStyleAlias{chapterpage}{chapterpage.hc}
\pagestyle{plain}

\setkomafont{chapter}{\normalfont\fontsize{32pt}{30.5pt}\selectfont}
\setkomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries\fontsize{32pt}{30.5pt}\selectfont}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*\headchapter{\@ifstar{\@sheadchapter}{\@headchapter}}
\newcommand*\@headchapter[1]{%
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{chapterpage}\refstepcounter{chapter}%
  \markleft{\thechapter\enskip#1}%
  \addchaptertocentry{\thechapter}{#1}%
}
\newcommand*\@sheadchapter[1]{%
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{chapterpage}%
  \markleft{#1}%
}
\newcommand\addheadchap[1]{%
  \clearpage\thispagestyle{chapterpage}%
  \markleft{#1}%
  \addchaptertocentry{}{#1}%
}
\makeatother
\deftocheading{toc}{\headchapter*{\contentsname}}

\begin{document}
\addheadchap{Test texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext texttexttext}
\lipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\raggedchapter` ... did not thought of that one. +1 btw: seen issues with the newest KOMA-update. Reported at komascript.de

Comment: Thank you, this solved the problem. However, I’m not sure why. Is it because we use `\usekomafont{chapter}` for this header?

Comment: It is because of `\parbox{\layerwidth}{...}`. In this layer `\layerwidth` is defined as `\textwidth`.

Comment: I thought, `\raggedchapter` only worked with `\chapter` but in this case it modifies the `\leftmark`. This is the part I don’t understand.

Comment: `\raggedchapter` is a only a hook inside `\chapter`. Changing this command you can change the alignment of the chapter head. The default definition of `\raggedchapter` is `\raggedsection` and `\raggedsection` is defined as `\raggedright`. So you could change `raggedchapter` to `\raggedright` if you want.